# Inline pictures with description

Tags: html, css, image, inline

I need to make inline a picture with a description and just a picture. It was ok to make 2 pictures inline using div block:inline, but when I added a desctiption to the first picture I couldn't do it inline - as you see on the screenshot my first div tends to have a lot in width (but margin:0 and width is fixed)
How to make it inline?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16415767/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-10-13%2015.30.13.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16415767/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-10-13%2015.30.56.png

Comment: used to display:inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `p` has style `display: block`. It is standard, browser default styling for paragraphs.

This way it will always take up `100% width`, but if the `width` is explicitly set on a `display: block` element, the remaining space is filled with automatic `margin`.

The solution is to set `p` to have `display: inline-block`.

---

If you have issues with aligning, you might try using floating elements.

*CSS Float* - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: appreciate your help! Thank you, Janos